# Storing different objects in an array java

Tags: java, arrays

What I need to do is storing different objects of an "Obstacle" super class in an array, and then perform the same actions as if I had one. So I need to be able to draw all the objects and also make them collide with the ball class.

So I tried to put all the instances of an object in an array in a for loop, and then I tried to paint them. But I can't figure out how to use the functions on the objects if they are stored in an array.

I tried to do this:

```
for(int i = 0;i<objects.length;i++){
            objects[0].paint(g);
        }
```

but the "paint(g)" part is just highlighted in red and it doesn't work.

If someone could help me I would be really happy! I haven't stored objects in arrays before, so I'm kind of clueless as what to do.

I also tried making the for loop like this:

```
if(i>=1 && i<15){
                Obstacle star = new StarObstacle(rand.nextInt(400),rand.nextInt(400));
                objects[i]= star;
                star.paint(g);
            }
```

Here they actually show up, but the stars are just flying all over the screen, so something must be changing x and y values all the time.

edit: sorry accidentally added the whole code instead of only the part I need help on. 
It's the for loop in the Main(int x,int y){} scope

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main extends JPanel implements KeyListener {

    Ball b;
    TriangleObstacle o;
    BorderObstacle border;
    StarObstacle s;
    Player player;
    int bounceCount=0;
    Object[] objects;
    Random rand = new Random();

    Main(int width, int height) {
        //create a new black ball at the center of the screen
        b = new Ball(width*0.5f, height*0.5f, 3, 0,0,0);

        //make a border around the window
        border = new BorderObstacle(width, height);
        objects = new Object[30];


        //setup a triangle obstacle
        o = new TriangleObstacle(width*0.3f, height*0.7f, 200, 50);
        s = new StarObstacle(400,300);
        player = new Player();
        this.addKeyListener(this);
        this.setFocusable(true); //needed to make

        for(int i = 0; i < objects.length;i++){
            if(i==0){
                objects[0]= new Player();
            }

            if(i>=1 && i<15){
                objects[i]= new StarObstacle(rand.nextInt(400),rand.nextInt(400));
            }

            if(i>15){
                objects[i]= new TriangleObstacle(30,30,rand.nextInt(400),rand.nextInt(400));
            }
        }

    }

    public void update() {

        //move over all obstacles and check whether they should bounce the ball
        border.bounceBall(b);
        o.bounceBall(b);
        s.bounceBall(b);



        if(player.bounceBall(b)){
            bounceCount++;

        }


        //move ball based on speed and location
        b.move();
        player.move(); //updates my player object.


        this.repaint(); //runs the paint method on the object
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        g.drawString("Amount of bounces on Player: " + bounceCount, 300, 100);
        b.paint(g);
        o.paint(g);
        s.paint(g);
        player.paint(g);
        border.paint(g);




    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int width = 800;
        int height = 600;

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pinball"); //create a new window and set title on window
        frame.setSize(width, height); //set size of window
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //set the window to close when the cross in the corner is pressed
        Main m = new Main(width,height-22); //-22 to account for menubar height //create a new object and runs constructor for initial setup of the program
        frame.add(m); //add the content of the object to the window
        frame.setVisible(true); //make the window visible


        while (true) { //keep running a loop
            //each time the loop is run do
            m.update(); //run the update method on the object
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10); //stops this part of the program for 10 milliseconds to avoid the loop locking everything. Now the screen has time to update content etc.
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int code = e.getKeyCode(); //gets input as keycode.
        if(code==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            player.setRight(true); //sets the movement for right to true, making it move by 5 pixels in the positive direction, for each update.
            player.setLeft(false);
        }
        if(code==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            player.setLeft(true);
            player.setRight(false);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { //keyReleased setting them to false to prevent the object to keep moving.
        int code = e.getKeyCode();
        if(code==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            player.setRight(false);
        }
        if(code==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            player.setLeft(false);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write your own method paint(Graphic g) in your classes "Player", "StarObstacle", "TriangleObstacle".

something like this:

```
 class TriangleObstacle extend Obstacle {
   public paint(Graphics g) {
     g.drawPolygon (...);
   }
 }
```

Also, avoid to use an array of Objects (Objects[]). Better use your superclass Obstacles for the array (Obstacle[] myObstacle = new Obstacle[30];

And don't put the Player object inside the array of Obstacle it wouldn't make sense.

At final you could have:

```
Obstacle[] myObstacles = new Obstacle[30];
Player player = new Player();
....
for (Obstacle obstacle : myObstacles) {
  obstacle.paint(g);
}
player.paint(g);
```

Comment: Omg thank you so much, I'm so stupid!

I wrote Objects instead of Obstacles, I don't even have an Objects class :P
Thanks a lot.

Comment: you're welcome ;-) But note that even if you don't have your Objects class, Object is  the superclass for any class in Java. It's invisible, but every classes that don't extend a class will be extending "Object" by default and therefore inherit all its methods (toString, equals...) :
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html

Comment: Another question:
(this is an assignment btw, it's not my decision to put all objects including the player inside thearray)

Now that I've put all my objects into the object array, I can only access the superclass functions. 
For example I can't say objects[0].move();   where my player object is located.

How do I access subclass methods in the array?

Comment: class Obstacle should be abstract (abstract class Obstacle {  ... }) and have a declaration of "void move();" method. Each subclass who extend Obstacle will implement "void move()" method.

Comment: Yes but I overwrote the move method in my subclass.

Comment: Actually nvm looking back I don't have a move method in my Superclass, I made one in my subclass

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
for(int i = 0;i<objects.length;i++){
            objects[0].paint(g);
        }
```

Doesn't achieve what you want because you are always accessing index 0. 

Try this:

```
for(int i = 0;i<objects.length;i++){
            objects[i].paint(g);
        }
```

This allows you to access and paint each object present on the index represented by `i`. I can't guarantee that this will solve the problem, but it is **a** problem.

Comment: Oh sorry, yea I know it will only access index 0, it was just to test if it would actually accept the paint method.
It doesn't even register the "paint" method. 
The method is in the superclass Obstacle, and I'm trying to use it on the objects stored in the array.

Comment: You probably aren't passing your Graphics object, 'g', to the method (Assuming this loop is not in your paint method)

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the object and use the correct index so :

```
objects[0].paint(g);
```

should be

```
((Observer)objects[i]).paint(g);
```

However this is completely the wrong approach. Please read up on java generics. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

You should be using a List or some other collection with an upper bound wildcard eg

```
List<? extends Observer>
```

Which will provide type safety.

Answer (score 0):

You must create an array of `Obstacles` instead of `objects`, the in your Obstacles interface add a method definition called `paint()`. Then you have to override the `paint()` method in every implementation of Obstacles. And when you call paint method in objects of the array it will call the corresponding method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an array, can you put the objects in a list? Something like...

```
List<Obstacle> someList = [however you populate your array, just populate the list instead];

for(int i = 0; i<somelist.length; i++) {
    someList.get(i).paint(g);
}
```